# Select products by condition in another table

Tags: php, mysql

Iam working with joomla joomshopping component and now I faced a complicated problem. I need to select product from database which are in range of extra_field condition what imean by that.

We have two tables

jshopping_products

```
product_id | product_name | extra_field_1 | extra_field_2
1          | my_product   | 1             | 2
2          | my_product2  | 1             | 3 
3          | my_product3  | 4             | 3
```

extra_field_values

```
id         | field_id     | name          
1          | 1            | 100
2          | 2            | 200
3          | 2            | 300 
4          | 1            | 150
```

And i want to select all products in 100-120 range for extra_field_1 and 200-205 for extra_field_2 so result should be first product product

my sql which i tried look like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM jshopping_products a, jshopping_products_extra_field_values b WHERE (b.name >= 100 AND b.name <= 120 AND there is a problem ");
```

How can i pair this two tables?

EDITED ***********

```
$query = "
SELECT  
  ".$prefix."jshopping_products.* 
FROM
  ".$prefix."jshopping_products
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_2 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_2 = field_2.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_7 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_7 = field_7.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_8 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_8 = field_8.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_9 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_9 = field_9.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_10 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_10 = field_10.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_11 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_11 = field_11.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_12 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_12 = field_12.id
   JOIN ".$prefix."jshopping_products_extra_field_values field_13 ON ".$prefix."jshopping_products.extra_field_13 = field_13.id
WHERE
  field_10.`name_cs-CZ` BETWEEN 0 and 999999999
";
```

thanks to respones i managed to make this anyway it gives me only 1 product and i know for sure in extra_field_10 there is about 100 values in range of 60-10000 with over 200 products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT distinct jshopping_products.*
FROM   jshopping_products
   JOIN extra_field_values field_1 ON jshopping_products.extra_field_1 = field_1.id
   JOIN extra_field_values field_2 on jshopping_products.extra_field_2 = field_2.id
WHERE
    field_1.name BETWEEN 100 AND 120 AND
    field_2.name BETWEEN 200 AND 205
```

Comment: somehow works but buggy it gives me only one product even there is a 500 products and ranges can be realy wide p.e. ma extra_field_10 has about 100 values form 60-10000 but when i give range form 0-999999 ti gives me only one product

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw your edit. If you aren't searching, e.g., field_7, don't join it. It will only return rows that have an existing related field value for each join. If you need to join them for some reason then change them all to "LEFT JOIN". (Sorry about formatting — apparently the ipad has no backticks.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to join with the `extra_field_values` table twice, once for each column in `jshopping_products` that you're joining with it

```
SELECT a.*
FROM jshopping_products a
JOIN jshopping_products_extra_field_values e1 ON a.extra_field_1 = e1.id
JOIN jshopping_products_extra_field_values e2 ON a.extra_field_2 = e2.id
WHERE e1.name BETWEEN 100 AND 120
AND e2.name BETWEEN 200 AND 205
GROUP BY a.product_id
```